Hi everyone, I'm testing smart contracts on the Sepolia Testnet and need some test ETH. the faucet dont want to work with me because im too new
Im a new developer, ive been traing to achive the imposible, making a monitoring bot that interect with my smart contract, ive never done any develop before this is my first try, I just need some Sepolia ETH to test my Frankeinstaein. Nothing but respect for developers this stuff is HARD. havent got a good sleep for tow weeks now.  Please !!!
Wallet adress
0x03e4fC60205784Bee8f4bd4106dc3fD590F785d7

im also new to this space. You can use this link below
https://cloud.google.com/application/web3/faucet/ethereum/sepolia
